# New to Javascript Obfuscation.. Why is it not executing?

Tags: javascript, html, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I am trying to run some Java script that has been obfuscated, but for some reason nothing is happening... my file is called test2.js and has this code in it:

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('L 6;6=\'p\';r c A(){1.2("3").0=""q(6<B){1.2("h").0+="C. s I o n k? I u l m 5 p <4>"}y q(6>w){1.2("h").0+="x D!. s I o n k? I u l m 5 6 <4>"}1.2("3").0+="<a 9=\'#\' 7=\'g();\'>e i, j d 5 f</a><4>"1.2("3").0+="<a 9=\'#\' 7=\'g();\'>e i, j d 5 f</a><4>"8 b}c g(){1.2("3").0=""1.2("h").0+="e i, j d 5 f<4>";1.2("3").0+="<a 9=\'#\' 7=\'v();\'>z H</a><4>"8 b}c v(){1.2("3").0=""1.2("3").0+="<a 9=\'#\' 7=\'t();\'>E M K J, F G?</a><4>"8 b}c t(){1.2("3").0=""8 b}',49,49,'innerHTML|document|getElementById|NPCResponseWindow|br|is|GetCharHP|onclick|return|href||false|function|name|Hi|Player|nicetomeetyou|NPCTalkWindow|NPC|my|today|your|HP|you|help|399|if||Can|END|see|Beginnings2|450|Go|else|Same|Beginnings|400|Hello|away|Lets|shall|we|here||again|this|var|do'.split('|')))
```

My HTML file has this:

```
<script src="test2.js"></script>

<HTML>
<BODY>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="NPCTalkWindow"></div></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <div id="NPCResponseWindow"> <a href='#' onclick='Beginnings();'>Begin Conversation</a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

But nothing is appearing except for the begin conversation. Any help? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just guessing: move the script tag to the end of the file. Probably the elements the code uses are just not existing, when it executes

Comment: Is it really the obfuscation which is breaking the code? Did you debug it before obfuscating it?

Comment: Obfuscated scripts are prone to errors—check your browser's console log. If you're only intending to minimise the file size, simply uglifying it and enabling gzip compression would do the job. Obfuscation rarely justifies the original intent—if you want to keep anything secret, **do not send it to the client**.

Comment: I am not trying to hide it, merely making it harder for a novice to find the code. At this point, Client side execution wont work for me. I did try the code prior to obfuscating it and it worked like a charm. I also moved the script to the end. Still nothings. Thanks for the suggestions/comments so far.

Comment: "I am not trying to hide it, merely making it harder for a novice to find the code" --- it makes no sense.

Comment: The script probably isn't being run at all as your HTML markup is invalid. Put the script before the `</body>` or within a `<head>` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As expected, they are errors on the unobfuscated code :

```
var GetCharHP;
GetCharHP = '399';
r    // there is an error here, add the ;
function Beginnings() {
    document.getElementById("NPCResponseWindow").innerHTML = ""
    if (GetCharHP < 400) {
        document.getElementById("NPCTalkWindow").innerHTML += "Hello. Can I help you today? I see your HP is 399 <br>"
    } else if (GetCharHP > 450) {
        document.getElementById("NPCTalkWindow").innerHTML += "Go away!. Can I help you today? I see your HP is GetCharHP <br>"
    }
    document.getElementById("NPCResponseWindow").innerHTML += "<a href='#' onclick='nicetomeetyou();'>Hi NPC, my name is Player</a><br>"
    document.getElementById("NPCResponseWindow").innerHTML += "<a href='#' onclick='nicetomeetyou();'>Hi NPC, my name is Player</a><br>"
    return false
}

function nicetomeetyou() {
    document.getElementById("NPCResponseWindow").innerHTML = ""
    document.getElementById("NPCTalkWindow").innerHTML += "Hi NPC, my name is Player<br>";
    document.getElementById("NPCResponseWindow").innerHTML += "<a href='#' onclick='Beginnings2();'>Same here</a><br>"
    return false
}

function Beginnings2() {
    document.getElementById("NPCResponseWindow").innerHTML = ""
    document.getElementById("NPCResponseWindow").innerHTML += "<a href='#' onclick='END();'>Lets do this again, shall we?</a><br>"
    return false
}

function END() {
    document.getElementById("NPCResponseWindow").innerHTML = ""
    return false
}
```

And add a doctype to your HTML
And move the script at the end of the file (juste before )
You can't hide javascript code it's to easy yo unobfuscate with online services

Comment: `r    // there is an error here, add the ;` <-- what does it mean?

Comment: The Doctype, Semi Colon and moving to end of the file is what did it. Thanks to all of you!

Comment: @zerkms, the user obfuscated the code, I think the obfuscator maybe force all code to one line and and forgot to add automatic semicolons before obfuscation.

Comment: @ArnaudGueras so how `r;` is better than `r`? It is exactly the same statement. `;` there literally changes nothing.

Comment: I know, It was just a supposition about the fact his obfuscator could cause an error. But I know it the same thing, only if you minimize your code with a bugged minifier that don't  end all lines with `;`

Comment: But your advice would not change anything: `r;` statement is identical to `r`. They behave **exactly the same**.